# Unable to connect to named SQL Server instance in Oracle SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using SQLDeveloper 23.1.0.097 I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2016 database on a named instance. The instance name is `<machine name>\sql2016`.

When I enter this information:

[image]

I get a failure on test or retrieve database as shown.

Is it possible to connect to an instance, or do we need to move to the default instance.

Ben

Comment: In the hostname field you've entered `azuredevbox\sql2016`. The `\sql2016` isn't part of the host name, it's called an instance name, and it requires that the SQL Browser service is running on the target server and is accessible via udp/1434. The SQL Browser service is responsible for resolving that instance name to the TCP port number that the instance is actually listening on, then the client can connect to that TCP port (which also needs to be accessible).

Comment: If this GUI tool can't work with instance names, which is probably the case, you'll need to consult the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool on the target server and check the Server Protocol settings for the `sql2016` instance to see which TCP port number it's listening on, then you can enter that into the Port field.

Comment: i would avoid named instances if possible, esp. when using java based apps (which you seem to be using). Just find out the IP/port it's running in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and use that

Answer (score 1):

Named instances don't listen on a fixed IP port by default.  To connect just [reconfigure the instance to listen on a fixed port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16) and connect using the hostname (without the \sql2016 instance name) and the fixed port you chose.  If there are no other instances using port 1433 you can configure it to listen on that.